# load external page in bootstrap modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a link like this

```
echo "<a href=\"profile.php?name=".$row['name']."\">".$profile."</a>";
```

And I have another page

```
<?php
    $profile = $_GET['name'];
    echo $profile;
?>
```

Now what I want is when user click on that link bootstrap modal box will open that another page. How can I do that? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="testing" href="http://fb.com/">Hye</a>

<iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testing").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var link = $("#testing").attr("href")
        $("#frame").attr("src",link);

    })

})
</script>
```

This will change link on click on a tag.
But still you can check bootstrap js for opening modal :)

Comment: Is this Working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use iframe in modal box , And pass your url in iframe src.

Comment: Can you please explain more? How can I pass the url in iframe src?

Comment: use jquery or js to get url from your a tag as this will generate after page loading because php execute before that .

Comment: when user click , call a js function, get url and set iframe , and then open modal by bootstrap function , do not forgot to use preventdefault otherwise it will try to open that link